Dynamic field exposure based on user authorization in Spring Boot controllers
I developed a Spring Boot application where I have a set of controllers that connect to a common service layer. I don't mind using any protocol (REST, GraphQL, gRPC, etc.) for the communication between the controllers and client. Here's the architecture overview:
Controllers communicate with a service to retrieve data.
Based on the Authorization level of the user, I want to modify the response data before sending it back.
For example:

If the user is an Admin, they should see all fields, like username and address, of other users.

If the user is a Regular user, they should not see sensitive fields like username and address of others.


Now, my challenge is this:

Uniform Service Layer: I want to keep the service layer common and reusable across multiple controllers, but apply different Authorization rules in each controller.
Multiple Authorization Levels: There may be different authorization levels across various controllers, and I need a solution that allows me to adapt this in a clean and maintainable way.
Dynamic Field Exposure: I need a mechanism that dynamically adjusts the fields returned to the client based on the user's authorization level.

How can I structure the architecture so that:

Controllers are split based on user roles or authorization types, but they all connect to the same underlying service.
Each controller only returns the appropriate fields depending on the user’s authorization.

Would you suggest any pattern or practice that works well with Spring Boot for this?
Example:
Consider a service method that returns a User object with fields like:
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    // getters and setters
}

If the user calling the API is an Admin, they should receive the full User object:
{
  "username": "morteza.j8",
  "address": "Mashhad",
  "email": "morteza@jalambadani.ir",
  "phone": "09123456789"
}

But if the user is a regular user, the response should only include a subset of the fields:
{
  "email": "morteza@jalambadani.ir",
  "phone": "09123456789"
}

How can I achieve this field filtering in the most efficient and maintainable way across multiple controllers and services?
Thank you!

You want to get different results from the same URL depending on the privileges of the user accessing that URL. This is fundamentally contrary to the REST philosophy, which states that your requests should be stateless. If you do this, you will have problems with caching. Since GET requests are idempotent, they are almost always cached by middleware, so you will have situations where users retrieving data from cache may see information they do not have access to.

This answer doesn't address my question. I never mentioned returning different results from the same URL. I'm talking about separating controllers for different roles if needed, but having all of them call the same service. The challenge is applying authorization logic at the service level while keeping the architecture clean. The caching concern isn't relevant here

@MortezaJalambadani If you have different controllers, why don't you just make different database queries through the service layer using projections.

read more about designing, you need to learn more :/

1- you can use JsonView and annotate your fields accordingly.
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation
2- You can also define cutpoints and AOP to filter sensitive fields that you annotated with your custom annotation
